# How to update parent class in a jpa single_table inheritance?

Tags: java, jpa

I have a JPA inheritance with a class `ContactDTO` that is extended by `UserDTO` with *Single_Table* strategy:

```
package ch.ffhs.cryptomess.server.dto;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorColumn;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorType;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;
import javax.persistence.Version;

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Transactional
@Entity(name = "ch.ffhs.cryptomess.server.dto.ContactDTO")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "discriminator", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "ContactDTO")
@Table(name = "user", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
        "username", "discriminator" }))
public class ContactDTO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7706720499337697645L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "user_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "user_id_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 10)
    @Column(name = "id")
    protected Long id;

    @Version
    protected Long version;

    @Column(name = "public_key", length = 255)
    protected String publicKey;

    @Id
    @Column(length = 50, updatable = false)
    protected String username;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "contacts", targetEntity = CommunicationDTO.class)
    protected Set<CommunicationDTO> communications = new HashSet<CommunicationDTO>(
            0);

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        final ContactDTO other = (ContactDTO) obj;
        if (username == null) {
            if (other.username != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!username.equals(other.username))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public Set<CommunicationDTO> getCommunications() {
        return communications;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getPublicKey() {
        return publicKey;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public Long getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result
                + ((username == null) ? 0 : username.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    public void setCommunications(final Set<CommunicationDTO> communications) {
        this.communications = communications;
    }

    public void setId(final Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setPublicKey(final String publicKey) {
        this.publicKey = publicKey;
    }

    public void setUsername(final String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setVersion(final Long version) {
        this.version = version;
    }
}
```

and:

```
package ch.ffhs.cryptomess.shared.dto;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import ch.ffhs.cryptomess.server.dto.ContactDTO;

import com.google.gwt.view.client.ProvidesKey;

@Transactional
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "UserDTO")
public class UserDTO extends ContactDTO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3078472527069117428L;

    @Column(length = 80)
    protected String password;

    @Column(name = "is_account_non_expired", columnDefinition = "BIT")
    protected boolean isAccountNonExpired;

    @Column(name = "is_account_locked", columnDefinition = "BIT")
    protected boolean isAccountLocked;

    @Column(name = "is_credentials_non_expired", columnDefinition = "BIT")
    protected boolean isCredentialsNonExpired;

    @Column(name = "is_disabled", columnDefinition = "BIT")
    protected boolean isDisabled;

    /**
     * The key provider that provides the unique ID of a contact.
     */
    public static final ProvidesKey<UserDTO> KEY_PROVIDER = new ProvidesKey<UserDTO>() {

        @Override
        public Object getKey(final UserDTO item) {
            return item == null ? null : item.getId();
        }
    };

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public boolean isAccountLocked() {
        return isAccountLocked;
    }

    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return isAccountNonExpired;
    }

    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return !isAccountLocked;
    }

    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return isCredentialsNonExpired;
    }

    public boolean isDisabled() {
        return isDisabled;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return !isDisabled;
    }

    public void setAccountLocked(final boolean isAccountLocked) {
        this.isAccountLocked = isAccountLocked;
    }

    public void setAccountNonExpired(final boolean isAccountNonExpired) {
        this.isAccountNonExpired = isAccountNonExpired;
    }

    public void setAccountNonLocked(final boolean isAccountNonLocked) {
        this.isAccountLocked = !isAccountNonLocked;
    }

    public void setCredentialsNonExpired(final boolean isCredentialsNonExpired) {
        this.isCredentialsNonExpired = isCredentialsNonExpired;
    }

    public void setDisabled(final boolean isDisabled) {
        this.isDisabled = isDisabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(final boolean isEnabled) {
        this.isDisabled = !isEnabled;
    }

    public void setPassword(final String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

If I do a merge or create on an `UserDTO`-enity, I want the `ContactDTO`-entity to be created/updated as well in the database. Is there any way to achieve this, without handling both entities seperately?

Thank you for helping!

Comment: you want what ContactDTO object to be updated too? You mean you want the fields of the superclass of the UserDTO object to be updated? They ought to be if the JPA impl is doing its job

Comment: If you do a merge or persist on a UserDTO entity instance, there is no ContactDTO, only the UserDTO which maps to one row in the defined "user" table.  This row should have values for all fields mapped in the UserDTO - java inheritance means that is all fields mapped in UserDTO as well as the parent ContactDTO definition.  Please give more info if this is not what you mean

Comment: Yes, what I want is that the fields of the superclass (ContactDTO) are updated, if I update UserDTO. I am new to JPA and assumed that there should be a row for each type in the user-table with the particular discriminator. But I think I got it now. The discriminator is only used for the end of the inheritance hierarchy.   If I create a UserDTO only one row is created and also merged if I merge the ContactDTO of this instance. Thank you guys for helping me .